# Ideas on a PowerShell class design for Json data

Tags: json, powershell, class

I have the following [class](https://github.com/Douda/PSSymantecCloud/blob/master/Source/Private/InternalClass.ps1) (called AllowListStructure) that creates an empty "skeleton" and methods to fill this structure that can then be converted to Json.

The issue is that it creates the empty structure all the time. For example, I have the following structure :

```
{
    "remove": {
        "Applications": [],
        "Certificates": [],
        "webdomains": [],
        "ips_hosts": [],
        },
        "windows": {
            "files": [],
            "directories": []
        },
        "linux": {
            "files": [],
            "directories": []
        },
        "mac": {
            "files": [],
            "directories": []
        }
    }
}
```

The original goal is to have the class with just an empty object, and just use the methods I need  to add the corrects fields,values on their correct levels without the empty fields

In the below example, I'd need this:

```
{
    "remove": {
        "Applications": [
            {
                "processfile": {
                    "sha2": "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
                    "name": "Aurelien test.exe"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

instead of :

```
{
    "remove": {
        "Applications": [
            {
                "processfile": {
                    "sha2": "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
                    "name": "Aurelien test.exe"
                }
            }
        ],
        "Certificates": [],
        "webdomains": [],
        "ips_hosts": []
    },
    "windows": {
        "files": [],
        "directories": []
    },
    "linux": {
        "files": [],
        "directories": []
    },
    "mac": {
        "files": [],
        "directories": []
    }
}
```

Any ideas how I could design this class to start with an empty object, and some methods let's say to :

- Create a "root hive" (here "remove")
- Create a level 2 Hive (applications / Certificates / etc)

I already have the methods to fill this objects, I just have no ideas how to creates the "branches" on a need basis only

Comment: To paraphrase your question so I understand it, you have a custom Powershell class that you want to serialise (you didn’t show how you’re doing this, btw) so that empty properties don’t emit json? I’m not sure of an idiomatic way to do that, but you could convert your class instance into an intermediary representation using a nested hashtable or pscustomobject and serlaize *thaf* to json. You can then just omit properties from the intermediary where they are null or empty in the class instance and they’ll be left out of the json.

Comment: Apologies I didn't want to add too many information and mostly focus on the class itself.
The way I serialize it is just with a "$object | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10" when the object is ready for conversion.
I could actually work this way, and try to convert only the non-empty properties. as I never worked with classes before, I thought I could do it from the class itself but I can work with the output too. Thank you